# Error when importing mathjs in Angular 9 CLI webworker

Tags: angular, angular-cli, mathjs, angular-devkit

I am currently trying add a webworker to my Angular 9 project using Angular CLI 9.1.7.
This webworker should run some calculations using mathjs 7.

However, importing mathjs into the webworker always results in the following error in the browser console.
If I don't import mathjs, the worker runs without a problem.

```
index.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/seed-random/index.js (index.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../node_modules/mathjs/es/function/probability/util/seededRNG.js (seededRNG.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../node_modules/mathjs/es/function/probability/pickRandom.js (pickRandom.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../node_modules/mathjs/es/factoriesAny.js (factoriesAny.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../node_modules/mathjs/es/entry/pureFunctionsAny.generated.js (pureFunctionsAny.generated.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

The referenced line is

```
var GLOBAL = typeof global === 'undefined' ? window : global;
```

and is part of the [seed-random](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/seed-random/blob/04f50d84870872bf38ea6283b1846202acf9ef44/index.js#L7) library used in mathjs.
I know that `window` is typically undefined in a webworker, however `global` should be set as far as I understand.
In the webpack config that the angular-devkit uses internally, I found the [follwing section](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/27d1200b187185be5ab0f79995dee6ccd6791d92/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/worker.ts#L31):

```
{
  plugins: [new WorkerPlugin({
    globalObject: false,
    plugins: [getTypescriptWorkerPlugin(wco, workerTsConfigPath)],
  })],
}
```

There, I already tried setting `globalObject` to `self` or `this` in my local `node_modules` folder, however this did not solve the problem.
I also don't see an option in the `angular.json` file to provide any additional configuration for the webworker to fix this problem, so I am unsure what to do to make this work.
In the [mathjs documentation](https://mathjs.org/examples/browser/webworkers/index.html), I found an example of using it in a webworker, so I assume it should also be possible using the Angular CLI.

I created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dominikks/angular-cli-webworker-mathjs-error) with a minimal working example. If you run it with

```
npm install
npm start
```

you can see the described error in the browser console.

So my question is: How can I use mathjs in an Angular CLI webworker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs/issues/1867) on the math.js GitHub where another workaround was proposed: 
It seems to be sufficient to just change the import from

```
import { sqrt } from 'mathjs';
```

to

```
import { sqrt } from 'mathjs/dist/math.js';
```

to fix the webworker.

This workaround is fairly simple and seems to work. However, this problem might be solved in future versions of math.js. It might make sense to check the issue for updates on this.